# How to replace number to random value in R?

Tags: r, random

I want to change the numbers of the data frame to random values (numbers).

```
x = c("010-1234-5678",
          "John 010-8888-8888",
          "Phone: 010-1111-2222",
          "Peter 018.1111.3333",
          "Year(2007,2019,2020)",
          "Alice 01077776666")
    
    df = data.frame(
      phoneNumber = x
    )
```

For example,
`John 836-3816-9361` is the output (random number) that I want, and I want to change other numbers related with `Phone`, `Peter`, and so on.

I just type `random <- sample(1:9,1)`, but I do not know the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one wants to replace all numbers, the `gsubfn` package can be useful.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("[0-9]", \(x) sample(0:9, 1), df$phoneNumber)
```

This replaces all digits with a random number. Naturally, this approach works better if the data is [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), here for example one could raise some objection to having names, years and phone numbers mixed in one column called `phoneNumber`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stringr::str_replace_all()` which can apply functions to regex matches.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

set.seed(5)

df %>%
  mutate(res = str_replace_all(x, "\\d+", \(x) str_pad(sample(10 ^ (nc <- nchar(x)), 1) - 1, nc, pad = "0")))

           phoneNumber                  res
1        010-1234-5678        888-6858-2254
2   John 010-8888-8888   John 221-3796-1832
3 Phone: 010-1111-2222 Phone: 402-1526-7238
4  Peter 018.1111.3333  Peter 825.3877.4482
5 Year(2007,2019,2020) Year(3599,9035,9012)
6    Alice 01077776666    Alice 90000945625
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this base R approach. We would extract the phone numbers, mask them with 11 random digits, and then put them back to their original places. Note that this method will not change any digits in `"Year(2007,2019,2020)"`, if this behavior is what you want.

```
rand_mask <- function(x) {
  m1 <- regexpr("\\b\\d{3}([-.]?)\\d{4}\\1\\d{4}\\b", x)
  phones <- regmatches(x, m1)
  m2 <- gregexpr("\\d", phones)
  rand <- replicate(length(m2), sample.int(10L, 11L, replace = TRUE) - 1L, simplify = FALSE)
  regmatches(phones, m2) <- rand
  regmatches(x, m1) <- phones
  x
}
```

Test

```
> set.seed(1234L)
> rand_mask(x)
[1] "954-8453-1659"        "John 537-3347-3723"   "Phone: 941-7326-8253" "Peter 791.4505.7250"  "Year(2007,2019,2020)"
[6] "Alice 08790795282"   
> rand_mask(x)
[1] "589-6578-2214"        "John 796-5386-2547"   "Phone: 036-2830-5595" "Peter 440.1591.4329"  "Year(2007,2019,2020)"
[6] "Alice 34955828570"   
> rand_mask(x)
[1] "815-7526-4562"        "John 268-7295-6144"   "Phone: 827-2728-3732" "Peter 960.8214.9580"  "Year(2007,2019,2020)"
[6] "Alice 28834025451"
```

---

Update

This one replaces all digits with random numbers.

```
rand_mask2 <- function(x) {
  m <- gregexpr("\\d", x)
  regmatches(x, m) <- lapply(lengths(m), \(n) sample.int(10L, n, replace = TRUE) - 1L)
  x
}
```

Test

```
> set.seed(1234L)
> rand_mask2(x)
[1] "954-8453-1659"        "John 537-3347-3723"   "Phone: 941-7326-8253" "Peter 791.4505.7250"  "Year(0879,0795,2825)"
[6] "Alice 89657822147"   
> rand_mask2(x)
[1] "965-3862-5470"        "John 362-8305-5954"   "Phone: 401-5914-3293" "Peter 495.5828.5708"  "Year(1575,2645,6226)"
[6] "Alice 87295614482"   
> rand_mask2(x)
[1] "727-2837-3296"        "John 082-1495-8028"   "Phone: 834-0254-5121" "Peter 656.7306.9729"  "Year(1707,7594,3930)"
[6] "Alice 55233202082"
```